# my terminal inserts and enters the letter "Y" after most git commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Myself and a coworker have started experiencing an odd issue where the "Y" character is inserted and then entered after nearly every git command. (Git add. , git commit, git push etc)
[image]
I am using Visual studio and typing my commands in the terminal window.

This issue does not break any functionality, it's just weird and very hard to google.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of the new setting:

`Terminal > Integrated: Auto Replies`

- see [v1.64 Release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_automatic-replies)

Do you have anything in this setting: `"terminal.integrated.autoReplies"`?

The feature is supposed to be opt-in so it shouldn't be doing that unless you have something in that setting.  Unless there is a git extension that is doing that "for you".  You could look through any git extension settings you may have installed to see if they enable an `auto replies` feature - I don't think the built-in git extension does.

In your case if you don't have a `"terminal.integrated.autoReplies"` that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This was it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Even I had this similar issue with the vscode terminal in windows. Its kinda irritating when it keeps adding that "Y" after git commands automatically. (I did not turn on the feature. This is the default behaviour)

Add this to your vscode settings.json file and it should get disabled.

> "terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
> "Terminate batch job (Y/N)": null   }

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I must have updated or something without realizing, because this only happened recently to us.